# super() does not pass arguments when instantiating a class extended from Object in Chrome V8

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, v8, babeljs

The code below logs false in Chrome V8 but logs true in Babel. The [feedback from Google](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=597493#c1) said that logging false is how it is supposed to be while logging true is a bug of Babel. I looked into the ES6 specs and still couldn't understand the mechanism behind this. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

```
class NewObj extends Object{
  constructor(){
    super(...arguments); // In V8, after arguments === [{attr: true}]
                         // is passed as parameter to super(),
                         // this === NewObj{} in V8; 
                         // but this === NewObj{attr: true} in Babel.
  }
}
var o = new NewObj({attr: true});
console.log(o.attr === true);
```

Comment: I don't understand the response to that bug; a `super()` call is most certainly allowed to include an argument list, and the Object constructor is supposed to pay attention to its argument.

Comment: It's a Chromium bug. I've tested on Microsoft Edge. It returns `true`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact the feedback you got on that Chrome bug is correct. Some things did change here from ES5 to ES6. Babel can't really do anything about it, and Edge didn't yet change it. Or it's an erratum :-)

The [ES5 `new Object(value)`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.2.1) spec says that it returns an object value that is passed in.

In ES6, you have to check the sections on [`[[construct]]` of builtins](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-built-in-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget) and the [`Object(value)` function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-value). And the first statement of that is

> If *NewTarget* is neither `undefined` **nor the active function**, then
>   Return [*OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinarycreatefromconstructor)(*NewTarget*, "%ObjectPrototype%").

So if you are doing `new Object({…})`, it will still return the `{…}` argument. But when you are calling it from `super()` or as `Reflect.construct(Object, [{…}], MyCustomTarget)`, so that *`new.target` is not `Object`*, then you'll just get a new object constructed from `MyCustomTarget.prototype`, and the argument is ignored.

Comment: Good find.  Have to wonder why the change from 5->6, since you really would expect it to work as per the OPs code.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Well, it didn't really *change* from ES5, because ES5 did not have super calls/new.target. Plainly invoking `new Object(…)` still works as always. It's just that from subclasses, `Object` works *differently* than "normal".

Comment: Right, yes - that makes sense.